# Can't connect GitKraken standalone version with GitHub

Tags: github, gitkraken

There is no GitHub option in GitKraken. There is GitHub Enterprise, GitLab, Bitbucket, Azure, Jira but no GitHub option in the preferences. Anyone has had a similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you click the "+" button in the top bar, you open a New Tab with many options. You can create a new repo hosted on GitHub, or close an existing repo hosted on GitHub

[image]